# cant find if a number is odd/even in a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

To reduce test time, I want reduce the number of rows process in my trigger. Should be easy but cant make it work.

- original version doesnt have `IF` and works ok
- this version with `IF` also work ok and insert all the same rows as original, so all cars has a random_id > 0 *(even and odd)*

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tracker_gps.avl_traffic_tracker_new()
    RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$

  DECLARE
      int_newcar_id bigint;       
  BEGIN    
      -- GET CAR_ID
      SELECT INTO int_newcar_id
          car_check
      FROM avl_db.car_check(NEW.car_id, int_source_id);

      IF int_newcar_id > 0 THEN
          INSERT INTO avl_db.avl_pool
          VALUES ( ...
          );      
          RETURN NEW;  
      ELSE 
          RETURN NULL;  
      END IF;
  END;
  $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;

  CREATE TRIGGER avl_traffic_tracker_insert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON tracker_gps.traffic_tracker_avl
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE tracker_gps.avl_traffic_tracker_new();
  ```
- then when change to `IF (int_newcar_id % 2) > 0 THEN` or `IF (int_newcar_id % 2) = 0 THEN` 0 rows are inserted **and should return the odd or even rows**
- So I create a new function to double check and with and both produce the expected correct result so only happen inside the trigger.

  ```
  IF (2 % 2) > 0 THEN -- or 1 % 2
     RETURN 300;
  ELSE 
     RETURN 500;
  END IF;
  ```

Comment: Is there a question involved?

Comment: What does `car_check` return?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Have different sources, and convert to a local autonumeric field. And as I say, this return different_id all `>0` odds and even

Comment: obviously, `car_check` returns only even numbers

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Nope `= 0` also return 0 rows

Comment: Of Course it does. 0%2 = 0. What do you expect for `IF (int_newcar_id % 2) > 0`?

Comment: I mean `IF (int_newcar_id % 2) = 0 THEN` also return 0 rows. I want reduce the number of rows to half. the id is autonumeric so half should be even and the other half should be odd

Comment: All the logic is in `car_check` that might return no rows or nulls or whatever.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz As I explain in the question `IF int_newcar_id > 0 THEN` return all rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done, I even use one of your answers to double check the even odd syntaxis

Comment: What does "car_check" function return ?? I suspect it returns boolean value (as suggested by name). In this case always 1.

Comment: @arturro as I say, I  get data from different sources. This check the local database to see if car is already there, if car is already there then return the id already assigned otherwise generate a new id and return that id. if I use `NEW.car_id` instead get same bad behaviour

Comment: Raise some notices in your code to help debug this. Log `new_car_id % 0` and add a log line to the `ELSE` branch.